# why update query in wordpress dosen't work

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i try to update in a table of wordpress. but i camt't. what is wrong?

The code I am using for this is the following code:

```
$wpdb->update( $wpdb->membership, array( 'status' => "token", 'transaction_id' => $resid ), array( "code", $code) );
```

Comment: Please provide error details; how is this failing?

Comment: You first parameter should be a string...Is it possible your table name is just `'membership'`?

Comment: `echo $wpdb->last_error` to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

i use this method and worked!

```
$wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->membership SET status = 'token' ,transaction_id = '" . $resid . "' WHERE code = '" . $code . "' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation).